# Como desactivar temporalmente o hacer que espere cierto tiempo, un window.scroll en JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Intento:**
Cuando el scroll  de mi documento llegue a cierta posición (captado por un window.scroll = function), realize un scroll hacia otro lugar.

**Problema**
Al comenzar a hacer el scroll, se vuelve a activar el window.scroll, moviendose solo unos pocos pixeles, volviendose a activar el window.scroll, asi infinitamente.

**Este es mi codigo:**

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {

    let docHeight = 4000; 

    if(1200<window.scrollY){
        scroll({
           top: docHeight,
           behavior: "smooth"
           })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor que podes hacer si queres que se haga un scroll al estar visible cierto elemento en la pantalla es usar la API Intersection Observer [documentacion de MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Alli se explica los problemas que soluciona en comparacion con otras soluciones que afectan el rendimiento de la pagina, algo parecido a lo que te pasa. De todas maneras te adjunto un ejemplo. Supongamos que quiero que cuando me desplace a un elemento parrafo (pintado de azul) y este sea visible me haga un scroll hasta el final de la pagina:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="scripts2.js" defer></script>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color: blue;" id="start">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; color: green;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate fugiat labore nostrum veritatis! Repellendus voluptatum corrupti quae! Fuga, minus omnis.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

en JS:

```
let start = document.getElementById("start") // seleccionamos el elemento desde el que queremos partir
let options = { rootMargin: "-200px" } // opciones para el intersector
let previousy = 0;

let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => { // declaramos un observer (entries es un array con los objetos observados)
  if(entries[0].isIntersecting){  // cuando el elemento sea visible en la pantalla (sea interceptado):
  let currenty = entries[0].boundingClientRect.y;
  if(currenty > previousy) window.scroll({top: 5000, behavior : "smooth" }) // 5000px con respecto a la parte superior del documento
    previousy = currenty;
  }
},options)
// *previousy y currenty las uso para que el scroll ocurra solo cuando nos movemos de arriba hacia abajo

observer.observe(start) // finalmente llamamos al observer y le pasamos el elemento objetivo y se realiza el scroll al llegar al elemento
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio perfectamente, es mas, lo implemente en otra funcion para mi pagina que estaba haciendo con window.scroll = f( )